# z elevation on recycler view item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to achieve this layout. When I click on an item (`CardView`) I should display an overlay on top of the entire activity (`9dp` elevation) and also elevate the item I clicked above the overlay (`>10dp`)

I have tried changing the properties `z`,`translationZ`, `elevation` and `cardElevation` with no success. Therefore I think the layout manager doesn't let its children rise above the overlay

Any ideas on how to workaround?

[image]

Comment: I can also try to put a dialog or popup window with the view I selected and then I’ll have the overlay for the background

Answer (score 0):

The elevation is added to the view width/height as margin.
Depending on the layout you might have to disable the children clipping.

Providing the layout xml may help us answer.